# How to edit this text under the product picture (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a Wordpress e-commerce to give support to, and I'm really struggling on how to edit this text under the product picture.

It is coming as default for every new product I create.

I have access only to the Wordpress admin account, which means I can't directly edit the files on the server, only edit using Wordpress tools.

P.s: We are using WooCommerce v3.3.3 and running Divi-child theme.

I've tried every menu and settings and I can't find where the hell this list is set.

Looking at the HTML code it's under the "woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper", but I can't find it in Wordpress Menus

```
<figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder"><img
        src="http://www.itschools.ie/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/placeholder.png"
        alt="Awaiting product image" class="wp-post-image" /></div>
<ul>
    <li>Delivery&nbsp;within&nbsp;10&nbsp; business&nbsp;days&nbsp;from&nbsp;date&nbsp; of&nbsp;order</li>
    <li>3‐year&nbsp;warranty&nbsp;with&nbsp;
        next&nbsp;business&nbsp;day&nbsp;onsite,&nbsp;full&nbsp;parts&nbsp;and&nbsp;labour&nbsp;cover</li>
    <li>No&nbsp;need&nbsp;to&nbsp;get&nbsp;quotes&nbsp;or&nbsp; undertake&nbsp;procurement&nbsp; process</li>
    <li>Additional&nbsp;upgrades&nbsp;and&nbsp; services&nbsp;available</li>
    <li>Detailed&nbsp;technical&nbsp; specification&nbsp;available&nbsp;in&nbsp; user&nbsp;guide</li>
</ul>
```

https://ibb.co/RDGhp4w (example image)

Does anyone have any idea what should I do to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

if this is not hard coded, it's coming through product description tab,

edit product-> product description

Comment: It is coming as default for every new product I create. I don't know how to set this

Comment: check single-products.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is excerpt for your product. It is not any menu content. So please try to check whether anything is in short description.

Comment: It is coming as default for every new product I create, and It doesn't show anything on the short description

Comment: You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-manager plugin to check all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, instead of editing WooCoommerce itself, I solved the problem going to Theme -> Editor

I found out that the file funtions.php had a function there with this  (list) set, and that was being used as default for every product added.

Solved and happy now :)